# const/non-const rvalue reference in overload resolution

Tags: c++, overloading, rvalue-reference

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void func(string &&a) { cout << "#1" << endl; }
void func(const string &&a) { cout << "#2" << endl; }
void func(int &&a) { cout << "#3" << endl; }
void func(const int &&a) { cout << "#4" << endl; }

int main()
{
  func(string("1"));                // call func(string &&) 
  func((const string)string("1"));  // call func(const string &&)
  func(1);                          // call func(int &&)
  func((const int)1);               // call func(int &&) not func(const int &&)

  return 0;
}
```

From the C++ standard:

> Standard conversion sequence S1 is a better conversion sequence than
>   standard conversion sequence S2 if
>   ...
>   S1 and S2 are reference bindings (8.5.3), and the types to which the
>   references refer are the same type except for top-level cv-qualifiers,
>   and the type to which the reference initialized by S2 refers is more
>   cv-qualified than the type to which the reference initialized by S1
>   refers.

It seems that the last call doesn't behave as expected. Who can explain it for me?

Comment: https://ideone.com/HWB3om output is "#1 #2 #3 #4". What compiler, compiler version, and compilation flags are you using?

Comment: gcc 6 and 7 call #4, gcc trunk emits a warning "type qualifiers ignored on cast result type" and calls #3. I think it's related to [gcc bug 80544](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=80544)

Comment: As what cpplearner's answer has explained, expression `(const int)1` has type `int`. P.S. In order to call `void func(const int &&a)`, the parameter has to be a xvalue, e.g. `static_cast<const int &&>(0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `(const int)1` is adjusted to `int` before overload resolution.

[[expr]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#6):

> If a prvalue initially has the type “*cv* `T`”, where `T` is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.